# How do I use variable of one activity in another activity in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have two activities classes. A value from user is taken in the first activity and stored in a integer datatype variable.

```
final EditText areanumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextplotarea);
areanumber1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int plotarea1 = Integer.parseInt(areanumber1.getText().toString());
            plotarea = plotarea1;
        }
});
```

When the next button is clicked it moves to next activity. Now I want to use that plotarea variable in another activity.

Second activity:

```
nextactivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);
nextactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        totallengthofwall = noofwalls * plotarea;
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), roomActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Comment: Use shared preference it will help you to save the data and then you can fetch the data to display in your next activity

Answer (score 1):

You should use **intent bundles** to pass variables trough activities.

E.G:

```
Intent secondAcvitity = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), roomActivity.class);
secondAcvity.putExtra("NameOfVariable", plotarea1);
startActivity(secondActivity);
```

**EDIT:**

**First activity:**

```
final EditText areanumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextplotarea);
areanumber1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int plotarea1 = Integer.parseInt(areanumber1.getText().toString());
            plotarea = plotarea1;
            Intent secondActivity = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), roomActivity.class);
            secondActivity.putExtra("NameOfVariable", plotarea1);
            startActivity(secondActivity);
        }
});
```

Then you should call intent in your new activity:

**Second activity:**

```
public .... onCreate(){
int newPlotarea1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("NameOfVariable", 0);
}
```

Comment: @WaqasAamer Is the name you want to give to the field inside the intent. You can choose the name you want. Just realise you need to use the same name for calling the intent in the next activity.

Comment: Yes, should be an space between `new` and `Intent`. Its edited now, sorry.

Comment: it is set in this activity                                                                          final EditText areanumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextplotarea);
            areanumber1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int plotarea1 = Integer.parseInt(areanumber1.getText().toString());
                    plotarea=plotarea1;
                }

            });

Comment: i want to use it in this activity here                                                nextactivity=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);
            nextactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    totallengthofwall=noofwalls*plotarea;

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), roomActivity.class));
                }

            });

Comment: Try `int newPlotarea1 = getIntent.getIntExtra("NameOfVariable", 0);`

Comment: public int waqas(){
            int newPlotarea1 = getIntent(getIntExtra("NameOfVariable", 0);
        }

Comment: public .... onCreate(){
int newPlotarea1 = getIntent.getIntExtra("NameOfVariable", 0);
}  the getIntent error is raising again and agian sirr

Comment: I cant try my code now, but Im sure it should work. Maybe some misspelling. I'll try it this afternoon.

Comment: thank you sir ..will be waiting for your kind your reply

Comment: Ok, `()` was missing from `getIntent()`. My fault sorry. Its edited now. Works prefectly, I have tested it.

Comment: it is not giving any type of error ...but it is also not getting the value

Comment: can you give me the email..that i send you the project

Comment: Sorry. I can't make your work. The onCreate() method is created by default when you create a new Activity. Check spelling, check values with Toasts, etc. It should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For this either you can make variable static or pass that variable using Intent.

```
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),roomActivity.class).putExtra("plotarea", plotarea));
```

Comment: if i just make the variable static then intent will be required or not

Comment: Intent will be required to go from one activity to another. Only difference is in this case you don't required to pass extra.  You can use ike this    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),roomActivity.class)

Comment: movenextarea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    double sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(plotarea);
                    oneside = sqrt;

                    Intent secondActivity = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), roomActivity.class);
                    secondActivity.putExtra("NameOfVariable", oneside);
                    startActivity(secondActivity);

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), exteriorwallActivity.class));
                }

            }); iam trying this code but the

Comment: bu the value is not changed...second activity code is this..int newPlotarea1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("NameOfVariable", 0);  i want to store the value of prevouis oneside variable in this vaiable